# postgresql check if json value exist with good performance for example:index

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to get rows where json value equals `'111'`

```
id   json
1    {"1":"111", "2":"222"}
2    {"1":"111", "3":"333"}
3    {"4":"444", "2":"222"}
4    {"4":"666", "2":"111"}
5    {"1":"777", "3":"888"}
```

Comment: Do you want id = 1 or id = 4 as well?

Comment: @S-Man I think he want ID (1, 2 and 4)

Comment: I want to improve my Performance by index

Comment: If you want to improve performance, then show us the query you are currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure about the keys to look `111` in for, you can simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM json_test
WHERE json::text LIKE '%"111"%';
```

See [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e522ec14ec0e64cbb6abacd460337ba5) here.

Comment: Which field is your index on? Share your DDL with index

Comment: on the json->value

Comment: If this answer your question then accepted.. You should ask other questions.. Because it is different question.. Do you want to put index and the context in this question are different.. @谈栋杰

Comment: @Mayank Porwal  I change my post

Comment: My query should have good performance if your index is on `json` column. The only concer  could be `like` operator, but it works weel if the search string is 3 chars.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b089d8eca20ada45144815f18e236bdf)

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE json ->> '1' = '111' 
      or 
      json ->> '2' = '111'
```

---

Updated data set:

[demo<>db:fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=796503189cca5ab013f4d756a846ee96)

```
SELECT 
    id, json
FROM 
    json_test, json_each_text(json)
WHERE 
    value = '111'
```

Expanding the json object (creates table with key/value pairs), filter the rows where value = '111'

Comment: actually I don't care about '1' , '2'  and I have 3 4

Comment: @谈栋杰: why don't you care about IDs 1 and 2? Both rows contain the JSON value `111`. What is the reason you don't want those, but the rows with IDs 3 and 4?

Comment: @谈栋杰 In your example row 1 and 2 have 111 for "1" and 4 for "2". Nothing for 3

Comment: other query needs '1' , '2' ,this query don't care about it,just check if exists

Comment: I added another way without caring for object keys

Comment: The op change the context this question.. You have good answer.. :)

Comment: json_each_text will traversing 4 times. It's not good performance